# pdflatex: How to automatically quit on compile error?

Tags: macros, errors, pdftex, compiling

See also [this question on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/1ydn7f/pdflatex_how_to_automatically_quit_on_compile/).

I want to automate running `pdflatex` over and over with `make` and `guard`.

However, when `pdflatex` encounters a syntax error, it hangs, preventing `guard` from being able to run it again.

Is there a command line flag, environment variable, or shell wrapper I can use to force `pdflatex` to quit on error rather than wait for more input?

Comment: Did you try `pdflatex -halt-on-error`?

Answer (score 29):

If you call `pdflatex` with the command line option `-halt-on-error`, the process will terminate at the first error.

Comment: Thanks: `pdflatex -halt-on-error file.tex` for easy copy-pasting :)

Answer (score 11):

If `file.tex` does not exist, `pdflatex -halt-on-error file.tex` hangs and prompts for a file name, instead of quitting.

To quit when the file isn't found, run `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex`.

Comment: The same issue seems to arise when the file does exist, but contains zero bytes. Your solution handles that case as well.

Comment: Alternative option includes `pdflatex -halt-on-error file.tex < /dev/null` (sh-similar shells only). If TeX cannot read anything from stdin it will terminate as well. // Fundamentally though, this is not an error, rather this happens whenever the file is "incomplete" i.e. you can type additional commands e.g. `\end{document}` so that the file forms a complete TeX document. But if you want to treat that as an error `</dev/null` works.

Comment: @user202729 still, using `nonstopmode` is clearer to the intent of running LaTeX in a scripted environment, and is more future-proof because of this.